# How to create an iterator for a map <string, map<string, classx> >?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

For a university work I have to implement a `map<string, map<string, class x> >`, where class x is a container of texts.
My question is the next: how an iterator for this class x will look? Do I have to create an intermediate iterator for accessing the map inside the map, or there is any way to access directly to class x?
I’ve heard something about the “find” option, but I don’t know how to use it with a map inside a map.
Thank you.

Comment: `map<string, map<string, class x> >::iterator`. But maybe you should better use `find()` with `auto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can make the code more readable, if you declare new types, handling your structure.

```
using inner_map = std::map<std::string, classx>;
using outer_map = std::map<std::string, inner_map>;
outer_map variable;
```

If you want to get to `classx`, you have to get to element in `inner_map`. However, to get there, you have to iterate over `outer_map`

```
for (outer_map::iterator outer_iterator = variable.begin(); outer_iterator != variable.end(); ++outer_iterator)
{
    for (inner_map::iterator = inner_iterator = outer_iterator->second.begin(); inner_iterator != outer_iterator->second.end(); ++inner_iterator)
    {
        // decltype(inner_iterator->second) == classx
    }
}
```

If you want to get to the `classx` and do not insist on explicit usage of iterators, you can use range-based for loop as IvanV pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using newer version of C++.

Then, you can simply use auto keyword with range-based for loop.

```
//entry1.first is key, and entry1.second is your map<string,classx>
for (auto const& entry1: yourMap) {

    //iterating through second map here
    // entry2.second is classx
    for (auto const& entry2: entry1.second) {

    }
}
```